# Confused insert statements

Tags: insert, insert-into

I'm copying all the records from one table to another table which will be having one additional column to keep track of the copying process. This additional column will be from some other table.

Im unable to insert data into the new table from these existing tables and need you people's input in that.

(I cant add one new column to the existing table. I must copy the data from it.)

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple.  I'm using a LEFT OUTER JOIN so that you don't omit any rows from the  first old table if there aren't any matching rows in the second old table.   You can adjust the selection to provide a default if the new column isn't nullable.  The new table should be created beforehand.

```
INSERT INTO newtable (colA,colB,...,newCol)
    (SELECT a.colA, a.colB,..., b.newCol
     FROM oldtable1 a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN oldtable2 b on a.colA = b.colA)
```

Comment: thanks......but my prob is i'm having 230 columns in the old table. So do i have to type them as shown above?? a.cola, a,colb,...a.col230???? is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: you could try omitting the column specifier and doing a `select a.*, b.newCol ...`  The number of columns being inserted is correct and in the same order, it might work.  Unfortunately I'm not able to try it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using SQL Server or MySQL or something else, but something similar to this should work.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col_for_tracking_copy)
SELECT col1, col2, 'some value' AS col_for_tracking_copy
FROM table_name2
```

You said that the additional column would be from 'some other table.' Could you be more specific? If you can JOIN to this other table, just add that to the above statement and remove 'some value'.